# Insert not updating views as it should

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

I have two models with a @Relationship set on them. Here, Employee can have many AttendanceLog, when I add AttendanceLog with Employee , it should update and reflect relevant Employee as well and update the view right? But it Employee only updates when I close the app and reopen after adding the attendance log.

```swift
/**
 ## Steps to recreate the issue
 - Start
 - Tap Add Employee in next screen
 - Tap first or any employee row item , tap Add Log in next screen, it adds  new log and reflacted in same screen
 - Go back, the log doesn't reflect in previous screen
 - Press back again and start, the log count doesn't update in employee rows.
 - Close the app and reopen the app the log count shows up , as it should.
 **/

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model final class Employee {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: Int
    var name: String
    var registrationDate: Date
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \AttendanceLog.employee) var logs: [AttendanceLog] = []
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.registrationDate = Date()
    }
}

@Model final class AttendanceLog {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var employee: Employee
    
    init(date: Date, employee: Employee) {
        self.date = date
        self.employee = employee
    }
}

@main
struct SwiftDataSampleApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Employee.self,
            AttendanceLog.self
        ])
        var modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        
        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                EmployeeList()
            } label: {
                Text("Start")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EmployeeList: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var employees: [Employee]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(employees) {
                employee in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(employee.logs.count)") // This doesn't get updated
                    NavigationLink {
                        LogView(employee:employee)
                    } label: {
                        Text(employee.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Employees")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    let seed = [
                        Employee(id: 1, name: "one"),
                        Employee(id: 2, name: "two"),
                        Employee(id: 3, name: "three"),
                        Employee(id: 4, name: "four"),
                        Employee(id: 5, name: "five")
                    ]
                    
                    for e in seed {
                        modelContext.insert(e)
                    }
                    try? modelContext.save()
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Employee")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LogView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var logs: [AttendanceLog]
    @Bindable var employee: Employee
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(logs) {
                log in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(log.id.uuidString).font(.caption2)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Attendance Logs")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    let log = AttendanceLog(date: Date(), employee: employee)
                    modelContext.insert(log)
                    try? modelContext.save()
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Log")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to "fix" this particualr problem, try this in your `AttendanceLog` model:

```
 @Relationship var employee: Employee?  // <--- here
```

Note that in `LogView` you should have `ForEach(employee.logs) { log in ...}`
to display only the `logs` of that employee. Note also you could just
use `let employee: Employee`, no need for the `@Bindable`

Comment: I figured that it needs to be optional after hit and trial. Here is comprehensive code. 

https://hastebin.com/share/urewaxenic.swift But. Thanks for the help. Also do we really need @Relationship Macro on Employee?

Comment: yes, you can do without the @Relationship.